# Cant pip-install mysql into venv on Mac OS Catalina for Django framework

Tags: python, django, python-venv

Dears, I can not install mysql or mysqlclient into my venv. Everytime I try, I am getting this errors:

However, I managed to brew-install it locally by using these steps: https://ruddra.com/posts/install-mysqlclient-macos/

It worked locally, but still, I can not create a proper venv with mysql or mysqlclient. 
I am using Django and PyCharm. Everytime I want to manage.py runserver, it asks me for mysqlclient.

Error when trying to pip install mysql into my venv:

```
Processing /Users/michaltarasiewicz/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/3e/4a/d0/506edab38d1bdf574b02c24805fcf7348a327297fcc285431d/mysql-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting mysqlclient
      Using cached mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85 kB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
      Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/michaltarasiewicz/Projects/Venvs/Django/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-install-v6y4fnwu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-install-v6y4fnwu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-wheel-8ds4c5v5
           cwd: /private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-install-v6y4fnwu/mysqlclient/
      Complete output (30 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
      running build_ext
      building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/include/mysql -I/Users/michaltarasiewicz/Projects/Venvs/Django/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
      gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
      ld: library not found for -lssl
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
      Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
    Failed to build mysqlclient
    Installing collected packages: mysqlclient, mysql
        Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /Users/michaltarasiewicz/Projects/Venvs/Django/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-install-v6y4fnwu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-install-v6y4fnwu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-record-8j227b7x/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/michaltarasiewicz/Projects/Venvs/Django/include/site/python3.8/mysqlclient
             cwd: /private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-install-v6y4fnwu/mysqlclient/
        Complete output (30 lines):
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
        creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
        copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
        running build_ext
        building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
        creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
        creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
        gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/include/mysql -I/Users/michaltarasiewicz/Projects/Venvs/Django/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
        gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
        ld: library not found for -lssl
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
        error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/michaltarasiewicz/Projects/Venvs/Django/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-install-v6y4fnwu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-install-v6y4fnwu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/v5/rxvfdtj967bcph1hj69s0k8m0000gn/T/pip-record-8j227b7x/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/michaltarasiewicz/Projects/Venvs/Django/include/site/python3.8/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have dependencies installed:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

You need at least GCC to be installed but check full list on the project page.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can link the `mysql-connector-c` back, then try to install mysqlclient. Like this:

```
brew unlink mysql
brew link --overwrite mysql-connector-c
pip install mysqlclient
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
brew link --overwrite mysql
```

Alternativly, if you have mysqlclient installed in the system, then you can use `--system-site-packages` when creating virtual environment:

```
python3 -m venv venv_name --system-site-packages
```

More information can be found in [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) documentation.